# How do I AliasMatch every alphanumerical request, but no other?

Tags: regex, apache, url-rewriting

I need to do a rewrite on all requests on a domain.
For now, I have this AliasMatch rule set :

> AliasMatch (.*) "/home/x/public_html/index.php"

Although, for security measures, I need to allow only alphanumerical (+ the slashes in the requests, along with GET variables).
Some directories do not need rewriting, in this case, all directories starting with "_".
I've been trying to write such a Regex, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Can you give some examples of matching and non-matching requests so we understand better what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For alphanumeric only matching, you'd want:

```
AliasMatch ^/[a-zA-Z0-9]+$ /home/x/public_html/index.php
```

Comment: Thank you! I changed it to ^/[a-z0-9|\/]+$ to include "/"s and refuse any upper chars and it works great ;)